# I need to loop this json in JS

Tags: arrays, json

i have this json in JS and need to loop the part:

```
"valores_p_prom":{"178":[{"Custo_sem_com_h":6,"Custo_c_com_h":16,"Total_horas":6,"Custo_hora":"normal","Com_h":10,"APagProm":36,"pay":60}],"185":[{"Custo_sem_com_h":5,"Custo_c_com_h":15,"Total_horas":6,"Custo_hora":"baixo","Com_h":10,"APagProm":30,"pay":60}]}
```

full json:

```
[{"Evento":"rr","JobId":"735","Datas":[{"dia":"2017-08-20","inicio":"5:00","fim":"11:00","n_horas":6}],"Morada":"r","Localidade":"Lisboa","Descriçao":"rr","npromotoras":"1","Soma_de_Horas":6,"Prom_escolhidas":["185","178"],"valores_p_prom":{"178":[{"Custo_sem_com_h":6,"Custo_c_com_h":16,"Total_horas":6,"Custo_hora":"normal","Com_h":10,"APagProm":36,"pay":60}],"185":[{"Custo_sem_com_h":5,"Custo_c_com_h":15,"Total_horas":6,"Custo_hora":"baixo","Com_h":10,"APagProm":30,"pay":60}]},"a_pagar":"186€","client_pagaiva":"229.48","cliente":"Greenmov","cliente_email":"cliente@cliente.pt","cliente_id":"36"}]
```

i have tryed :

```
var oo=JSON.parse(row[i].ev_fire);
var iu=oo[0].valores_p_prom;



if (iu===undefined) {} else {

$.each( iu, function( key, value ) {
    //arr.push( value );    
    console.log("key => "+key);//will output: 04c85ccab52880 and all such

    $.each( value, function( ky, val ) {
        console.log('ky => '+ky[APagProm]);//will output: name, firstname, societe
        console.log('val => '+val);//will output: name1, fname1, soc1
    });    
});
```

---

```
but i get key => 178  
val => [object Object]
```

please helpme

Answer (score 0):

i fixedit  using:

console.log("apagar À prom: "+val.APagProm);

tks